# How to allow a user to input a value during the msi installation of a windows service vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, installation, windows-installer

I currently have a windows service that is packaged up as an msi installer. However, during the installation i need the user to input their required filepath (to string) location. The filepath variable currently resides in my component class called MyNewService that is inherited from System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.

Is there anyway i can allow the user to define the filepath variable during installation?

Comment: the filepath is defined as a sting. It is a path used by my xml writer on where to write the xml files to. so for example the path could be c:\Temp\Logs\

Comment: It's not something that you have via some other well-known path? Why does the user want to configure this in the first place?

Comment: im relatively new to all of this so i wasnt sure of any other way to do it? the user wants the ability to change the file path location if needed. unfortunately its what they want.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the installer so the user can enter the value. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18834/Create-custom-dialogs-for-use-in-your-Visual-Studi) is what you are looking for or something along the lines.

Comment: Thanks for the link. i have followed it up to the point where i can create a text box to write the users input to a variable. however what should i do with the variable now?